# Mongodb sharded cluster backup

Tags: mongodb, backup, mongodump

I have a sharded mongodb database cluster.
I am using mongodump utility to take the backup.

```
mongodump --host <host> --port 27017 --db <db_name>  --authenticationDatabase admin -u <username> -p <password> --out ouput
```

Will I be able to take the backup of the entire database by running the above command against my mongodb router?

Tried running the above command.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: make sure the host and port are a MONGOS, not a MONGOD.  Should work fine.  You can get better backup times by backing up each MONGOD in parallel, but you need to stop the balancer before doing this.  Also, the idea of point-in-time comes into play.  May need to halt writes if wanting to back up all MONGODs in parallel.

Comment: Consider reading over this page https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/.